# How to set HelloWorld Template 0.99.5 to Portrait Orientation?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I'm trying to do this with changing files

**GameConfig.h**:

```
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone
```

And **App delegate**:

```
//#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController

    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
//#else

//[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

//#endif
```

App turns to Portrait mode, but Box2d bodies forced gravity to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit the file `RootViewController.m` at line 88:

```
return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
```

and change it to:

```
return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation));
```

This setting only takes effect when `GAME_AUTOROTATION` is defined as `kGameAutorotationUIViewController`, in `GameConfig.h`.

///////

Answer (score 5):

in case anyone need I realize that this is an old topic, but in case anyone comes across this problem in the future, here is my solution:

In the accelerometer function of HelloWorldLayer.mm the gravity is set with this line

```
b2Vec2 gravity( -accelY * 10, accelX * 10);
```

In order to simulate the desired effect in portrait mode, the line must be re-ordered to:

```
b2Vec2 gravity( accelX * 10, accelY * 10);
```